# Open data bound form on specific record

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am struggling to find an answer on this;

I have Form1 which contains a databound DataGridView table from a dataSet from a SQL server. Upon double click event of the row, I need to open Form2 to that databound specific ID. Now I understand that I can get each of the columns and loop through all the textboxes and add them in, but these seems very cumbersome and open to mistakes when there could be a large number of individual textboxes.

Instead I just want to open that form to the specific selected record. Something similar to how you could do with MS access...

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "Form2", , , "ID = " & recordID
```

Comment: You can add a constructor to Form2 that accepts an argument of the type represeting the `ID` (`Integer`, probably). If you don't know how to do it, you can instead add a public Property that accepts the same type of value. So you can do `dim frm2 as new Forms2() frm2.MyPublicProperty = [The ID] frm2.Show(Me)`. When the Form loads, read the Property value and set a Command Parameter value to this property value.

Comment: You can also simply use DataBindings (passing/sharing a BindingSource object, for example).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your help @Jimi. I used your solution by creating a new tableAdpter and adding a parameter which is passed to the new form, works perfectly.